# angular : How to export a service from a npm package

Tags: angular, npm

I have a service in my Angular 2 package I want to put on NPM with theses lines :

```
public showModal: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
public $showModal = this.showModal.asObservable();

public closeModal: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
public $closeModal = this.closeModal.asObservable();

public configModal: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
public $configModal = this.configModal.asObservable();
```

Subject variables are used like this : `myService.configModal(new ModalConfig());`
Observables are used with a subscribe to update my component data, show it or hide it.

Here is my index.ts who export my class :

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {ModalComponent} from "./lib/modal.component";
import {ModalService} from "./lib/modal.service";
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ModalComponent],
    providers: [ModalService],
    exports: [ModalComponent],
//  bootstrap: [ModalComponent]
})
export class ModalModule {}
```

How can I access to ModalService in another app ? I want my service to be a singleton too, So I can't export it and provide the service in my component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some days later, I found the solution to my problem.  I just have to add an export statement :

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {ModalComponent} from "./lib/modal.component";
import {ModalService} from "./lib/modal.service";

export {ModalService} from "./lib/modal.service";

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [ModalComponent],
    providers: [ModalService],
    exports: [ModalComponent],
//  bootstrap: [ModalComponent]
})
export class ModalModule {}
```